# When i send a http request, it can connect success but throw an exception if send request data

Tags: android, okhttp

In my android app, we use http request for getting data from server, and use okhttp3.0.1.
From the log, we find that some users network is connected.But when it begin to send request to server, it can find healthy connect(not in pool,new create),but throw an exception if send request data.

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:179)
at okio.RealBufferedSink.flush(RealBufferedSink.java:216)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream.finishRequest(Http1xStream.java:162)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:724)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$2(HttpEngine.java:723)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:711)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:566)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:242)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:199)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:161)
at com.myapp.okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:58)
```

okhttp version is 3.0.1
Anyone can tell me what problem it can be? server、network or client?
How can i check and fix it or reeduce the probability of occurrence?

add message------------------------------------------------
add code for calling okhttp.Class OkHttpStack override HttpStack which use in volley.

```
public HttpResponse performRequest(Request<?> request,
            Map<String, String> additionalHeaders) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
        int timeoutMs = request.getTimeoutMs();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = mClient.newBuilder();
        builder.connectTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

        com.ktcp.tencent.okhttp3.Request.Builder okHttpRequestBuilder = new com.ktcp.tencent.okhttp3.Request.Builder();
        String oUrl = request.getUrl();
        if(oUrl!=null && oUrl.indexOf("?")>=0)
        {
            oUrl = oUrl+"&timeforahj="+System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        okHttpRequestBuilder.url(oUrl);

        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        for (final String name : headers.keySet()) {
            okHttpRequestBuilder.addHeader(name, headers.get(name));
        }
        for (final String name : additionalHeaders.keySet()) {
            // 这里用header方法，如果有重复的name，会覆盖，否则某些请求会被判定为非法
            okHttpRequestBuilder.header(name, additionalHeaders.get(name));
        }

        setConnectionParametersForRequest(okHttpRequestBuilder, request);

        com.ktcp.tencent.okhttp3.Request okHttpRequest = okHttpRequestBuilder.build();
        Call okHttpCall = client.newCall(okHttpRequest);
        Response okHttpResponse = null;
        try {
            okHttpResponse = okHttpCall.execute();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw e;
        }
        StatusLine responseStatus = new BasicStatusLine(
                parseProtocol(okHttpResponse.protocol()), okHttpResponse.code(),
                okHttpResponse.message());
        BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(responseStatus);
        response.setEntity(entityFromOkHttpResponse(okHttpResponse));

        Headers responseHeaders = okHttpResponse.headers();
        for (int i = 0, len = responseHeaders.size(); i < len; i++) {
            final String name = responseHeaders.name(i), value = responseHeaders.value(i);
            if (name != null) {
                response.addHeader(new BasicHeader(name, value));
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Most user work success,but some user retun socketexception when its wifi is connected.
When i add some log,I find it can connect server.this function work ok.The connection is new create,not in connection pool.

```
 private RealConnection findHealthyConnection(int connectTimeout, int readTimeout,
      int writeTimeout, boolean connectionRetryEnabled, boolean doExtensiveHealthChecks)
```

but throw exception when send request as Exception stack above.
My question is the connection is create new ,means that it can connect to server,why it throw exception when send request.Two action is continues.

Comment: Can you please format your question and add the code that is causing the error?

Comment: Did i describe it clearly?

Comment: My question is the connection is create new ,means that it can connect to server,why it throw exception when send request.Two action is continues.